# how to get value of an element at point of postback to use in Page_Load method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm writing an ASP.NET form which uses a custom web service to populate a table based on values (the specifics of this are not important).

On the page are two ASP.NET Calendar controls, what I want to be able to do is make use of the AutoPostback behaviour of these to make a new web service call each time the `SelectedDate` of one of these changes, using its value as an input parameter.

Currently I set the value of the controls in the `Page_Load` (in an `if (!Page.IsPostBack){}` statement), and the first web service call includes both of these values. If one of these calendars is updated, I want a new web service call to be made, with the **Submitted value** from the calendar as a parameter, currently I can't get the request to contain anything but the initial value, which was set on the first page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting the code to call the web service in the on_changed event of the calendar control?

Comment: perfect, thanks, now have an issue where the second calendar is set to DateTime.Min, but i can sort this one myself! :)